# RC4 Encryption KSA key out of bounds

Tags: c#, algorithm, cryptography, rc4-cipher

I am implementing a RC4 algorithm in C# for my WPF app.

I followed this [pdf](https://www.math.washington.edu/~nichifor/310_2008_Spring/Pres_RC4%20Encryption.pdf) stating the algorithm.

The thing is, in the KSA, we ought to do : `j = (j + S[i] + (int)key[i % keyLengthInBits]) % 256;`.

That being said, I do not understand how this would work because the key ought to be from 5 characters long to 32 characters long (40bits up to 256bits).

So let's take an example with a 5 characters key ( I'll use the same as in the pdf I linked above) : *pwd12*. You go fetch the character of the key at the position `i % 40` (5 characters long is 40 bits). It's fine for the first 5 times because from `i = 0` to `i=4`, we have a value in the key (*pwd12*). Though here is the problem (from how I see it)  : when we are at `i=5`, we do not have any characters left in the key. Therefore we will get an `ÒutOfBounds Exception`.

How is it possible to works if we try to fetch a character in the key where  there is none? Obviously there is something I do not see in the algorithm because it does work otherwise it would not be used...

Comment: Hint: what's the modulo operator (`%`) for?

Comment: Return the remainder the division. Therefore it's not the keyLength in bits but the key length itself. Thanks for opening my eyes!

Comment: It is the key length in bits. The purpose of that expression is to select a single bit of the key. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase `key[i % keyLengthInBits]` is a way of saying "the i'th bit of the key". It does not mean the i'th entry in the key expressed as an array of bytes, each holding 8 bits of the key.

The equivalent C code would be something like:

```
int bit = i & keyLengthInBits;
((key[bit / 8] >> (bit % 8)) & 1)
```

Comment: Ok then `((key[bit / 8] >> (bit % 8)) & 1)` ,which I am not quite sure with, would be that : From what I understand of it, let's say we are at `i=5` and the key is still *pwd12* (40bits). it would be `bit = 5 & 40` which would give 0 and therefore `key[0/8] = 'p'`. From what I get of the `>>` operator, it does a right shift on the bit of 0 since `(bit % 8 = 0)` so p stays from 01110000. The `&1` makes it become 00000000. (From here I'm lost about why we would make it become 0...) 
I guess I'm wrong but from what I understand, this is how it goes in your two lines. @David Schwartz

Comment: @Marks You have it right. If `i` is 5, the code extracts the fifth bit of the key.

Comment: Then what if we are at the 52th iteration ( `i = 52` ). It goes 52 (00110100) & 40 (00101000) which gives 00100000 so `bit = 32`. `key[32/8] = key[4]` which gives 2 (still considering the key being *pwd12*). Right shift of 0 since `32 % 8 = 0`. So it ends up being 00000010 & 00000001 which gives 0. Therefore here again it would become `j = (j + S[k] + (int)key[0]) % 256;` ) being the result we have from the i % ketLengthInBits using the two lines you provided. Is that correct ? @David Schwartz

Comment: If `key[4]` is `00000010`, then as `i` goes from 32 to 39, it reads off the 32nd to 39th bits from right to left, outputting 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.

Comment: Reading from right to left is because of the `>>` right shift I'm assuming ? Even though it does not shift since it's `>> 0`, it does read it from the right.
Considering that, we still would go to 0 doing the `&1` since 01000000 & 00000001 gives 00000000. No ? @David Schwartz

Comment: Right. When `bit%8` is zero, we extract the rightmost bit by ANDing with 1. When `bit%8` is 1, we extract the second bit from the right by shifting right once and then ANDing with 1.

Comment: If `(key[32/8] >> (32 % 8)) & 1` (using again `i = 52` and the key *pwd12* ), then it becomes `(key[4] >> (0)) & 1`. `key[4]` being 2 becomes `(00000010 >> 0) & 1`. Right shift of 0 gives us `01000000 & 1` which leads us to `00000000` (let's say `int result = Convert.ToInt32("00000000",2);`). Then we can see it as `j = (j + S[i] + (int)key[result]) % 256;`. Because the way I understands it is that what we just did is to make the result of `key[i % keyLengthInBits]`. *Above code being in C#.* @David Schwartz